# Unsure if my complexity analysis is correct

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity, code-complexity

Attempting to find a Big-O estimation of this code chunk:

```
int a[][] = new int[m][n];
int w = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<m; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j<n; j++) {
        if ( a[i][j]%2 == 0) {
            w++;
        }
    }
}
```

I made an esimation and simplified: O(m)O(n)O(1) => O(mn)

It looks like all cases will be O(mn) because it doesn't matter if the O(1) operation executes or not, is this correct? Or are there best/worst/average cases?

Appreciate any insight!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `O(mn)` here because of the 2 loops (one of which is nested in another). O(1) doesn't make sense here. The `if` doesn't count. There is no break in it so it won't affect the whole traversal for both loops. There are no best or worse here, again because the `if` does not change the flow nor incrementing w affects the loops in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this will be always O(mn) because  if you count testing condition as operation then it does not matter if the body will be executed or not.

It would be only constant O(mn*1/2) but because 1/2 is just constant you can ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

In this code you provided, there is no upper bound on the nested loops, so you don't use the big-O complexity function, instead use big-Theta to describe the time complexity, and in your case, yes it is θ(nm) meaning that your algorithm will always take θ(nm) time, and there is no best/average/worst case here.